# Python lowriter call getting different result than from terminal

Tags: python, libreoffice, converters, libreoffice-writer

So, I'm trying to use lowriter to convert some files from doc/docx to pdf inside my program. When I run it like a sub process I get 'Application Error' like below

```
>>rest = subprocess.getoutput('lowriter --convert-to pdf --outdir ./data/temp_convert "<FILE_PATH>/file.docx"')
>>rest
'Application Error'
```

But when I run it directly form the terminal everything works fine:

```
$ lowriter --convert-to pdf --outdir ./data/temp_convert "<FILE_PATH>/file.docx"
convert <FILE_PATH>/file.docx -> ./data/temp_convert/file.pdf using filter : writer_pdf_Export
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Ps. This is an old script that worked before last week and I changed nothing since the last working build

Comment: Does the subprocess know where `lowriter` is located on your system? Try giving the full path to it

Comment: yes, it does. `which lowriter` returns the correct path using the subprocess and calling lowriter with the complete path gets the seme error